# Proving that $Y$ is independent of $X$ if $Y=XZ$ for some random variables $X,Y,Z$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Say $X$ is a random variable such that $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$, and $Z \sim N(0,1)$.
If $Y=XZ$, then are $X$ and $Y$ independent from each other? If yes, how can I show this?

Intuitively I would say that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, since $Y$ depends on $X$ by $Y=XZ$, but I know that my intuition may be wrong.

Comment: Intuitively, if someone told you the value of $Y$, would that in any way give you any information about what $X$ could be? Does that information affect how likely it is that $X=1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y\leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X=1)\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$ for every real $y$.

Now, denoting by $\Phi(y) := \mathbb{P}(Z\leq y)$, $$\mathbb{P}(X=1) = \frac{1}{2}$$ $$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(Z\leq y,X=1) + \mathbb{P}(Z \geq -y,X=-1) = \frac{1}{2}(\Phi(y) + 1-\Phi(-y)) = \Phi(y)$$ $$\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y\leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X=1,Z\leq y) = \frac{1}{2} \Phi(y)$$